# How to include additional numeric input in the Transformer architecture

Tags: transformer

I want to apply the [Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) architecture to my machine translation task, and provide the decoder with an additional parameter in the range of `[0,1]`. This parameter should provide the decoder with some additional information on *how* to translate the sequence, think, e.g., how pompous the resulting translation should be.

Although I have *some* idea on how to approach this task, I would like to ask for help and additional input. I have found a paper by [Libovický et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.04716), which studied multi-source sequence-to-sequence tasks. Here are some of the ideas that came to my mind:

- Use an additional encoder, to encode this (single) numerical value, and apply one of the approaches mentioned by Libovický et al. This *feels* strange in the sense that we are encoding only a single element, and attending to it.
- In a similar fashion, use an additional encoder, but this time instead of providing a single numerical value, create a sequence of length `n`, where all elements are the same input parameter. E.g., if the parameter was `0.5` and `n = 3`, the resulting sequence would be `[0.5 0.5 0.5]`. Then, use masked multi-head attention to attend to these output values. Note that this approach is based on my intuition only. I lack the needed experience to judge whether this approach could actually provide benefits over the previous one.
- Add an additional input to the decoder, applying masked multi-head attention to it, but not necessarily positional encoding. Then, sum up the result of this operation and the "standard" input, resume with this interim result. I believe that for this approach I would also have to create a "fake" sequence, where each element is the same numerical parameter.

To sum it up, I am looking for a way to provide the decoder with an additional input, in my case a single numerical value.